# Something about Gram-Schmidt Projections

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Recently I'm reading the book *Numerical Linear Algebra* and I have a problem in Lecture 8, Gram-Schmidt Orthogonalization. The following text is from the book.

> Let $A\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$, $m\geq n$, be a matrix of full rank with columns $\{a_j\}$. Consider the sequence of formulas
>   $$q_1=\frac{P_1a_1}{\|P_1a_1\|},\quad q_2=\frac{P_2a_2}{\|P_2a_2\|},\quad\dots,\quad q_n=\frac{P_na_n}{\|P_na_n\|}.$$
>   In these formulas, each $P_j$ denotes an orthogonal projector. Specifically, $P_j$ is the $m\times m$ matrix of rank $m-(j-1)$ that projects $\mathbb{C}^m$ orthogonally onto the space orthogonal to $\langle q_1,\dots,q_{j-1}\rangle$. (In the case $j=1$, this prescription reduces to the identity: $P_1=I$.) Now, observe that $q_j$ as defined by the formulas above is orthogonal to $q_1,\dots,q_{j-1}$, lies in the space $\langle a_1,\dots,a_j\rangle$, and has norm $1$.

I can't understand why $q_j$ lies in the space $\langle a_1,\dots,a_j\rangle$. Is there anyone who can help me? Thanks.

Comment: I find it easy to confuse which space is which.  Look at this example:  Let A be the matrix with columns (1,1) and (0,1).  Now project the 1,1 column onto the x and y axis.  Can you answer your question in this case?

Answer (score 1):

To explain how $q_j \in \mathrm{span}(a_1,...a_j)$, we need to think about orthogonal projectors. By definition, an orthogonal projector $P_j$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow A$ for a subspace $A = \mathrm{span}(a_1,...,a_j)$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, as illustrated in Figure 6.2 of Trefethen and Bau's *Numerical Linear Algebra*, $y - Py \perp A$ for $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Any vector mapped by $P_j$ will then lie in $A$, and can thus be expressed as a linear combination of $\langle a_1,...,a_j\rangle$ (point 2 above). Given this fact, $y - P_j y$ annihilates any vector $a \in A$, including $q_i, i \in {1,...,j-1}$, since they all lie in a subspace of $A$ spanned by $\langle a_1,...,a_i\rangle$ (this is point 1 above).

The third point is straightforward: $\|q_j\| =1$ after we normalize $q_j$ by its length.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation :) But it seems that these are based on the materials discussed in Lecture 6. Can I directly derive the three points, given what I have quoted in the problem description? Thank you very much.